# x64 MOV 32-bit immediate to 64-bit register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, instructions, machine-code, immediate-operand

The second instruction on this page in the code section:

[image: x86]

Looks like this: `MOV r9d, 0`.  Encoded like this: `41 B9 00 00 00 00`

The only problem is... There's no `MOV` instruction in the Intel x64 manual that takes a 4-byte immediate and puts it in a 64-bit register.

These are the instructions from the Intel manual:

```
B0+ rb          MOV r8, imm8 Move imm8 to r8.
REX + B0+ rb    MOV r8***, imm8 Move imm8 to r8.
B8+ rw          MOV r16, imm16 Move imm16 to r16.
B8+ rd          MOV r32, imm32 Move imm32 to r32.
REX.W + B8+ rd  MOV r64, imm64 OI Valid N.E. Move imm64 to r64.
```

The instruction appears to work, but how?

Comment: You missed [`REX.W C7 /0 id` `mov r/m64, imm32`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html), which sign-extends the immediate.  It needs a ModR/M byte, and it's not what your code is using, but your claim is not correct.  It's only useful with a memory destination, or with negative numbers where you can't use the implicit zero-extension of `mov r32, imm32`.

Comment: Fascinating chart. I found it in a google image search. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`r9d` isn't a 64 bit register. It is the low 32 bits of the `r9` register, as such it is a 32 bit register.